# Getting error as 'Run time error 1004 range of object _worksheet failed' Unable to find exact reason behind it

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code to generate Auto Serial Number in Column B and start from B15. It also depends upon Column C cells data records. when the C column cell will go empty at any point then the serial number will stop automatically in Column B.

```
  Sub AutoSRIn()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheet9

    ws.Range("B15").Select
    lrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

    Set myrange = ws.Range(Cells(15, 3), Cells(lrow, 3))

    For Each cell In myrange
        cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = i + 1
        i = i + 1
    Next cell

End Sub
```

But I am getting an error 'run time error 1004 range of object _worksheet failed at following line number'.

```
Set myrange = ws.Range(Cells(15, 3), Cells(lrow, 3))
```

The important and strange thing is that sometimes it works but if used in any other version like excel 2010 it is not working

I am trying to get a result through userform submit button. First, there is code for insert records in C column from C15 then Use this code to get the auto serial number for records.
Please Help Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`Cells()` without a worksheet qualifier will default to the active sheet, so

```
Set myrange = ws.Range(Cells(15, 3), Cells(lrow, 3))
```

will fail if ws is not the active sheet.

You need something like:

```
Set myrange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(15, 3), ws.Cells(lrow, 3))
```

Comment: If ws is not the active sheet then `ws.Range("B15").Select` would fail before. But you are right `Cells()` refers to the active sheet and `ws.Range(Cells(15, 3), Cells(lrow, 3))` will fail in case ws is not the active sheet.

Answer (score 1):

You could shorten the above code to

```
Sub AutoSRIn()

    With Sheet9
        lrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
        Set myrange = .Range(.Cells(15, 3), .Cells(lrow, 3))
    End With

    For Each cell In myrange
        cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = i + 1
        i = i + 1
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have mentioned the explicit/implicit sheet reference issues. But you still make use of an iteration through range objects (not bad in itself, but not necessary and slow on a large range).

**<sub>Alternatively try:</sub>**

```
Sub AutoSRIn()

With Sheet9
    Dim lr As Long: lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    If lr > 14 Then .Range("B15:B" & lr) = .Evaluate("ROW(1:" & lr - 14 & ")")
End With

End Sub
```

Btw, it's good practice to `Dim` all your variables to some `Data` type if possible (`Dim myrange As Range` and `Dim i As Long` for example)

Comment: Thanks to @JvdV. I noted your suggestions